# Why CSV file does not display columns as columns?

Tags: excel, csv, import-from-csv

[image: excel]

The semicolons are delimeters for every field, but they don't correspond to the columns A, B,C,D,E,F etc!
I downloaded this file, open it in Excel, but it shows them as rows - I can't separate data in every row

Answer (score 4):

This is due to fact that the default list separator on your system (and most of the system) is comma. This is a Windows setting that will be used by all programs that refer to it (Excel in this case).

***Option 1:***
You can use the feature 'Data -> Text to Column' wizard from ribbon and choose semicolons as separator to split columns.

***Option 2:***

```
- Go to Control Panel.
- Open the Regional and Language Options dialog box.
- Do one of the following: In Windows Vista/7, click the Formats tab, and then click Customize this format. In Windows XP, click the Regional Options tab, and then click Customize.
- Type a new separator in the List separator box.
- Click OK twice.
```

Hope this helps.